# How does the c compiler know how to place different types of values in allocated memory? (using malloc)

Tags: c

In this piece of code, I noticed the`malloc()` frees up memory of size of `(double *)` and `double`. So when the rest of the code is storing values in DataArray, how does the compiler know where to store those values in the memory?

```
int rows=100;
int columns=100;

double **DataArray, *DataRow;

DataArray = (double **)malloc(rows *sizeof(double *)+ rows * columns *sizeof(double));

for (i = 0, DataRow = (double *)(DataArray+rows); i < rows; i++, DataRow += columns)
DataArray[i]=DataRow;
```

Thank You!

Comment: "...malloc frees up memory.." - sorry you are going to have to explain that a little more, it makes absolutely no sense as written

Comment: What do you mean by "frees up"?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't "free up memory", it allocates it. (I'm not sure I understand your question at all, actually.)

Comment: Also, [you should prefer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/129570) `T *p = malloc(n * sizeof(*p))` to `T *p = (T *)malloc(n * sizeof(T))`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording! I meant to ask about the 4th line. Why does the code allocate for both type double* and double? I thought a variable of type double** could only hold values of type double*.

Comment: it is just memory - you're allocating standard memory. You can put anything in there that you want to using casting or whatnot, and there are caveats(alignment,cpu caching,...) when doing this, but malloc just takes a number of bytes as the argument, what you do with it is up to you.

Comment: o i see! thank you! i visualized malloc as allocated blocks of memory that is rigid in size. Now I know that it allocates it like one big bucket, where data can flow in like water!...sorry, but how do I choose you as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know how to organize the elements of a **two-dimensional array** in this way.

That memory is only one-dimensional as the compiler is concerned.

The code you show is explicitly compensating for that by allocating the space for a pointer to each row **and** enough space for all the rows and columns.

The `for` loop you posted is initializing all the row pointers, allowing later code to do a two-dimensional lookup by indexing, one-dimensionally, into the row pointers and then indexing again into the desired column.

Answer (score 0):

When the array operations ([]) are used, they generate the needed offsets to access/index the data pointed to by DataArray automatically.

Ex:

```
DataArray[0] is located at (char*)DataArray+(sizeof(double*) * 0 )bytes
DataArray[1] is located at (char*)DataArray+(sizeof(double*) * 1 )bytes
DataArray[2] is located at (char*)DataArray+(sizeof(double*) * 2 )bytes
```

Note, the previous pseudocode should not be confused with array arithmetic operations:

```
DataArray+0
```

is located at DataArray, but

```
DataArray+1
```

is located at DataArray+sizeof(double*)

Answer (score 0):

malloc takes an argument of type size_t (basically an integer type matching the 32 or 64 bits architecture you're compiling for). It doesn't "know" what your are allocating, in fact the expression row * sizeof(double *)+ rows * columns * sizeof(double) is here to compute the space you'll need to store rows array of pointer then the arrays.

Note that to store a matrix, you don't need such a
complicated and error-prone system. Remove the first part of DataArray containing pointers and access the row, col element using DataArray[row*columns + col]. The integer multiplication is not that a big deal compared to the savings in memory (especially on 64 bits systems). But then again you decide how you balance between CPU and memory.